# Aggregate function to count occurrences in set of arrays

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have several large tables that contains a similar column storing an array of identifiers. These are segmentation identifiers, that signals which segments the row belongs to.

A very simplified version of the data might look like this:

```
| score | segmentIds |
|-------|------------|
| 3     | [1, 2, 3]  |
| 22    | [3, 4, 5]  |
| 15    | [2, 4, 6]  |
```

Several different kinds of queries needs to know the distribution of the aggregated rows with respect to these segmentation identifiers. This is done by counting the number of occurrences of each identifier found within the set of integer arrays. Ideally this can be done by keeping a running count of how many times each identifier was found in an array.

Based on the above data, getting the average of the score and the distribution of segments, might give the following result:

```
avg(score): 13.333
distribution(segmentIds): {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 1, 6: 1}
```

I have written a custom aggregate function to accomplish this, but I was hoping a more efficient way (both from a time and space perspective) could be found. Worst case scenarios it needs to run on a few hundred thousand rows, where each row will contain a row with around 10-30 identifiers in the array.

```
CREATE TYPE array_union_type AS (
    a       int[],
    l       int
);

CREATE FUNCTION array_union_all(array_union_type, INT[], int) RETURNS array_union_type
AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN ROW($1.a + $2, $3);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL STRICT PARALLEL SAFE IMMUTABLE ;


CREATE FUNCTION array_union_combine(array_union_type, array_union_type) RETURNS array_union_type
AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN ROW($1.a + $2.a, $1.l);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL STRICT PARALLEL SAFE IMMUTABLE ;

CREATE FUNCTION array_count_final(array_union_type) RETURNS JSONB
AS $$ SELECT
    jsonb_object_agg(i, c)
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            i,
            COUNT(*) AS c
        FROM
            unnest($1.a) AS t(i)
        GROUP BY
            1) AS t
where
     c >= $1.l
$$ LANGUAGE SQL STRICT PARALLEL SAFE IMMUTABLE ;

CREATE aggregate array_count_agg(int[], int)
(
  SFUNC = array_union_all,
  STYPE = array_union_type,
  INITCOND = '({}, 0)',
  COMBINEFUNC = array_union_combine,
  FINALFUNC = array_count_final,
  PARALLEL = SAFE
);
```

I have created the custom type as I need to send around the "limit" parameter, that will ultimately discard any segments that occur less that the given time. This is not very pretty, but from what I could find it's not possible to pass additional parameters to the final function, so this seemed the only way to accomplish that.

From a CS perspective, concatenating arrays together thousands of time and then counting occurrences is not ideal. Rather it would be good to keep a running count as each row is processed, but I cannot figure out how to represent that state in PL/SQL.

I should note that this needs to run on Postgres on AWS RDS, so we cannot use C-functions.

Comment: I don't read all you post, but may be you need `distinct` which returns only distinct (different) values/rows for specified column. And than you may count occurrences for that values with subquery.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Thanks, I updated with some example data and desired results.

Comment: You could normalise you table by creating other table with segmentIds + connectionId that should be unique in table with score. Then it should be easier to manipulate data in sql request

Comment: We have considered that, but it makes the tables extremely large. There are many other pieces of data in the table that is also required for filtering and indexing, which all has to be duplicated. As each array in a row contains upwards of 30-40 elements, that would correspond to a 30x larger table. It could be normalized further, but that results in a number of joins that kills performance.